# String format exception when using Google OAuth sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website and I want to add external sign in via Google, Twitter, Facebook and some other providers. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Right now, I'm trying to get Google sign-in working. I registered my website with Google and got client ID and client secret. I keep these two values in PrivateSettings.config file which I keep out of source control for security reasons.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID" value="<snip>"/>
    <add key="GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET" value="<snip>"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And I'm referencing my file in Web.config

```
<appSettings file="PrivateSettings.config">
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

My project is based on template that VS2013 generated when I created this project. I followed the same creating process as in the tutorial I mentioned above (Individual User Accounts), which created some config classes in my App_Start folder. I modified Startup.Auth.cs file to add support for Google sign in, by uncommenting `app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()` bit and added reference to client id and client secret, like so:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
});
```

I also enabled ssl in the project properties.

When I launch my app (on local, I haven't deployed it yet) and try to log in via Google using my personal account, the login process fails in `public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)` method, at this line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

It throws `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0` exception. `loginInfo` is not null (checked while debugging, plus there is check before this line is executed that redirects if `loginInfo` is null) and contains my info from Google (mail, name).

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. This exception is thrown when there is problem in connection string. I'm using Entity Framework and MySQL. I had to follow this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w to enable ASP.NET Identity with MySQL provider. Now Google-OAuth works and so does traditional registration and login.